Why is Germany not among the signatories of the UN Convention on Jurisdictional Immunities of States and Their Property?
Germany is one of the countries that has ratified the European Convention on State Immunities, but has not (even signed) the UN Convention on Jurisdictional Immunities of States and Their Property.
Somewhat aside, France is in the opposite situation, they signed the UN one, but not the European one. The French Cour de cassation even stated that the UN Convention, even though not yet in force, embodies customary international law in this area. (And that piece rather implies that the French position is that European Convention, which France didn't sign, is somewhat obsolete.)
So, why is Germany not among the signatories of the UN Convention, unlike Austria, Belgium, Switzerland, or the UK, which have signed both?
(It seems among the signatories of the European Convention, besides Germany, the Netherlands, Cyprus, and Luxembourg also didn't sign the UN convention, but for the sake of making this a simple Q, I'm asking about the biggest fish in this pond.)

Immediate find: an ICJ case concerning restitution claims against Germany, and a German verbal note. In a number of cases in Poland, Greece and Italy complainants demand compensation for war crimes committed during WWII. Germany was always fighting these on multiple levels. How this fits together with the signing or not of the treaties is not immediately clear.

@ccprog: yeah, I was aware of those, but like you say, it's unclear how the UN treaty would impinge on that, if they were to sign it, especially what's "extra" [& relevant to those disputes] in the UN one that's not [already] in the European one that Germany has ratified.

If it’s not clear what signing implies, then I wouldn’t sign.
